# How to add a list using (api sendgrid) cakephp

Tags: api, web-services, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, sendgrid

I'm trying to make requests in external Web Services with Cake HttpSocket, I'm trying to create a new list I'm getting an error from api sendgrid

[body] => {"errors":[{"message":"request body is invalid"}]}

```
public function addemail() {
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $lista = array('name' => 'Teste');
    $retorno = $HttpSocket->post('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists', $lista,  
    array(
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer SG.XXXXXXXXX'
        )
    ));
    if ($retorno->isOk()) {
        debug($retorno->body());

    }
}
```

what is wrong? in the sendgrid documentation says that the body should be this way

{
"name": "listname"
}

Comment: Does it work if you try $lista = json_encode(array('name' => 'Teste'));

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer since it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to json encode the array like so:

```
$lista = json_encode(array('name' => 'Teste'));
```